# Finding max row_number inside a window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to calculate an Exponential Moving Average of 3 periods without the use of any loops. I got the math down and in order to calculate it, I have to do something like:

```
EMA(t) = SUM( Value(t) * K * (1 - K) ^ (n - t) )
```

Where `EMA(t)` is the moving average, `n` is the number of items to sum, `t` is the item and `K` is a constant.

So, I tried something like this in **T-SQL**.

```
select EMA03 = SUM( xValue * (0.5) * POWER( 0.5, MAX(rn) - rn ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY nClient ORDER BY myDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
  from ( select myDate
             , xValue
             , nClient
             , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY nClient ORDER BY myDate )
          from myTable ) A
```

But the problem is I can't use `MAX(rn)` inside a window function already. I have to somehow figure out how many rows the over clause contains and use it on my function. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the count in the subquery?

```
select EMA03 = SUM( xValue * (0.5) * POWER( 0.5, cnt - rn ) ) OVER
                   ( PARTITION BY nClient
                     ORDER BY myDate
                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                   )
from (select myDate, xValue, nClient
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nClient ORDER BY myDate) as rn,
             count(*) over (partition by nClient) as cnt
      from myTable
     ) A
```

Comment: the problem with this is that I get the count of how many dates I have for a specific client. That only works for the last EMA03. If I start on 'January 1st 2019', when my EMA is calculating the date 'January 4th 2019' the cnt value has to be 4. When my EMA is calculating, during the same select, the date 'January 10th 2019' th cnt value has to be 10. If I add the count inside the subquery, cnt will always be 10 (if myTable ends in January 10th 2019)

Comment: I need to somehow get how many rows are inside the partition that the SUM argument is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you

```
    select EMA03 = SUM( xValue * (0.5) 
        * POWER( 0.5, (select 
           count(distinct *) from myTable
          where nClient=A.nClient) x
           group by nClient
           ) - x ) ) 
       OVER 
       ( PARTITION BY nClient ORDER BY 
        myDate ROWS BETWEEN 
      UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
      CURRENT ROW )
     from ( select myDate
         , xValue
         , nClient
         , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( 
         PARTITION BY nClient ORDER BY 
           myDate )
      from myTable ) A
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add another layer of sub-query.

And while at it, let's use CTE's for readability sake.

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
  SELECT myDate, xValue, nClient
  , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nClient ORDER BY myDate)
  FROM myTable
), 
CTE2 AS
(
  SELECT c.*, max_rn = MAX(rn) OVER ()
  FROM CTE1 c
)
SELECT c.*
, EMA03 = SUM(xValue * 0.5 * POWER(0.5, max_rn - rn)) OVER (PARTITION BY nClient ORDER BY myDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM CTE2 c;
```